# Export a plug-in with linked source folders built into separate libraries (jars) doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, export, eclipse-jdt

I have the following setup:
there are several plug-in projects containing common utility and base classes, e.g.:

1. my.util
2. my.util.ui

And I have one plug-in which uses them. However, I'd like to not import these utility classes as plug-ins but use linked source folders. This is not a problem at all and the "workload" plug-in is e.g.

- my.actual.plugin

All three plug-ins are in the same workspace and the "actual" plug-in contains the usual "src" source folder and the following linked source folders "src.my.util" (links to my.util/src) and "src.my.util.ui" (links to my.util.ui/src). The linked source folders are bound to individual output folders (src -> bin , src.my.util -> bin.my.util , src.my.util.ui -> bin.my.util.ui).

Now, in the plug-in's build file (build.properties, or via the manifest editor) I wanted to specify that the sources of the two utility plug-ins are built into separate jars. Therefor, in the manifest editor under "Runtime" I added two additional jars ("New..." -> "my.util.jar" and "my.util.ui.jar") and under "Build" I set the appropriate linked src folders for these jars. The resulting build.properties file would be something like:

```
    source.. = src/
    output.. = bin/
    source.my.util = src.my.util/
    output.my.util = bin.my.util/
    source.my.util.ui = src.my.util.ui/
    output.my.util.ui = bin.my.util.ui/
    jars.compile.order = .,\
                           my.util.jar,\
                           my.util.ui.jar
    bin.includes = META-INF/,\
                    my.util.jar,\
                    my.util.ui.jar
```

Exporting this as a runnable jar works (let's assume for simplicity that it contains a class with a main method etc...).

However, trying to export this using the "deployable plug-ins or fragments" export wizard does bring up an error message like:

```
    <workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\compile.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
        <workspace>\my.actual.plugin\build.xml:167: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    <workspace>\my.actual.plugin\build.xml:138: <workspace>\my.actual.plugin\src.my.util does not exist.
    The following error occurred while executing this line:
    <workspace>\my.actual.plugin\build.xml:167: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    <workspace>\my.actual.plugin\build.xml:138: <workspace>\my.actual.plugin\src.my.util does not exist.
```

Even when I switch on the "Use class files compiled in the workspace" option in the export wizard this error comes up.

When I don't use separate runtime jars, it works, but it's just not what I want ;-)

Oddly enough, when I export the ant build script (Export... -> General / Ant Buildfiles) the paths are correctly expanded (translated from the "virtual" relative links to absolute paths). And the ant script compiles correctly. Why the hack does it not work for exporting as a plug-in?

I hope anyone has some suggestions? Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3):

I see that no one else has answered this yet, so I will provide an answer/opinion that you may not like.

I strongly suggest that you avoid the use of linked source folders in your plugin projects.

The reason that you are getting the errors that you see is because PDE uses an alternative mechanism for building projects.  It does not use the .classpath and .project files to determine project structure.  Rather, it uses MANIFEST.MF and build.properties.  It also does not use Eclipse's resource abstraction and hence linked folders are not recognized by PDE.

There may be some hacking that you could do to trick PDE into finding your linked source folders, but this wouldn't be a portable solution.

Instead, I'd recommend splitting things up so that you have multiple plugins so that you don't need to copy source folders around.

Comment: You're right, I don't really like the answer ;-) What keeps me wondering, though, is whether the "create ANT build script from project" export wizard (which DOES correctly convert the linked paths) is the one used/provided by PDE? Anyways, I now changed this exported ant script to extract my "actual" plug-in's version information and create an appropriate jar file with the version information (like they are exported by PDE) and it neatly integrates the specified jars using the linked source folders. It could get some refinement to extract information from build.properties, though...

Answer (score 1):

I have filed a bug report : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=457192
A related bug report is: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=66177

I think it should be solved